# How to detect transparent area click OR if user draw in transparent area in canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, cordova, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

I'm drawing an image onto a canvas using drawImage. It's a PNG that is surrounded by transparent pixels, like this:

How can I detect a drawing move path in the transparent part of that image on the canvas? I want to detect if a user draws in a transparent part.

I am trying this [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-canvas-drawing-files/) and I did as showing in the [tutorial](https://devdactic.com/ionic-canvas-drawing-files/).

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = draw;
img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";

function draw() {
  // draw original image in normal mode
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Check it out full code on [Github](https://github.com/gokujy/ioniccanvas.github.io)

Check it out live demo [IonCanvas](https://ioncanvas.sitesforhosting.co.in/)

Comment: It might help if you can demonstrate what you have tried so far.

Comment: @IronAces I am just showing the above image in a canvas. And now I want to detect if user clicks or draw on a transparent area.

Comment: You've already mentioned that in your question, but what have you attempted to address your issue? I see no evidence of that.

Comment: See the question I edited, I did only this in the ionic app. I want detent transparent area in the canvas.

Comment: @IronAces I added link of code and live demo, links in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out is a pixel is transparent get the pixel using [`ctx.getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and look at the alpha value.

### Example

```
// assumes ctx is defined
// returns true if pixel is fully transparent
function isTransparent(x, y) { // x, y coordinate of pixel
    return ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3] === 0; // 4th byte is alpha
}
```

Comment: It's coming false in both image and transparent area, please check I edited the question and added link of live demo.

Comment: Yes, it's working but I want to check inside the image. Ex. if the user clicks on the man it comes false but if the user click on another side of the image it will come true.